# Behaviour of Windows authentication mode, with forms child element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

When configuring ASP.NET authentication, what is the behaviour supposed to be when you set the authentication mode to `Windows`, yet have a child `forms` element?  For example, the following configuration is given as the default [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
   <forms 
      name=".ASPXAUTH" 
      loginUrl="login.aspx" 
      defaultUrl="default.aspx" 
      protection="All" 
      timeout="30" 
      path="/" 
      requireSSL="false" 
      slidingExpiration="true" 
      cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" 
      enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
   </forms>
   <passport redirectUrl="internal" />
</authentication>
```

However I see zero documentation of what is meant to happen here.  All documentation of the child `forms` element assumes that authentication mode will be `Forms`.  It's particularly odd that this isn't documented because this is the default.  So why does the `Windows` authentication mode have a `forms` child element?  Does the child element get ignored and it's just there as an example of what you might want if you were to switch mode to `Forms`, or does it do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just for the sake of an example. I cannot point you to any documentation but looking at the code, it looks like the *forms* settings are read only when the *authentication* mode is *forms*.

*Below is from [FormsAuthenticationModule.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationModule.cs)*

`public void Init(HttpApplication app) {
            // authentication is an app level setting only
            // so we can read app config early on in an attempt to try and
            // skip wiring up event delegates
            if (!_fAuthChecked) {
                _fAuthRequired = (AuthenticationConfig.Mode == AuthenticationMode.Forms);
                _fAuthChecked = true;
            }
                        if (_fAuthRequired) {
                // initialize if mode is forms auth
                 FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
                 app.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnEnter);
                app.EndRequest          += new EventHandler(this.OnLeave);
            }
        }`

Please note that *FormsAuthentication.Initialize* is called only when the *mode* is *forms*, which reads the *forms* setting from web.config file.

The code is from [FormsAuthenciation.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs) file

`/// 
        ///    Initializes FormsAuthentication by reading
        ///    configuration and getting the cookie values and encryption keys for the given
        ///    application.
        /// 
        public static void Initialize() {
            if (_Initialized)
                return;
             lock(_lockObject) {
                if (_Initialized)
                    return;
                 AuthenticationSection settings = RuntimeConfig.GetAppConfig().Authentication;
                settings.ValidateAuthenticationMode();
                _FormsName = settings.Forms.Name;
                _RequireSSL = settings.Forms.RequireSSL;
                _SlidingExpiration = settings.Forms.SlidingExpiration;
                if (_FormsName == null)
                    _FormsName = CONFIG_DEFAULT_COOKIE;
                 _Protection = settings.Forms.Protection;
                _Timeout = (int) settings.Forms.Timeout.TotalMinutes;
                _FormsCookiePath = settings.Forms.Path;
                _LoginUrl = settings.Forms.LoginUrl;
                if (_LoginUrl == null)
                    _LoginUrl = "login.aspx";
                _DefaultUrl = settings.Forms.DefaultUrl;
                if (_DefaultUrl == null)
                    _DefaultUrl = "default.aspx";
                _CookieMode = settings.Forms.Cookieless;
                _CookieDomain = settings.Forms.Domain;
                _EnableCrossAppRedirects = settings.Forms.EnableCrossAppRedirects;
                _TicketCompatibilityMode = settings.Forms.TicketCompatibilityMode;
                 _Initialized = true;
            }
        }`